# Bootstrap 4 responsive navbar collapsible button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar, responsive

I'm trying to code a navbar using bootstrap 4, that will show a collapsible button in xs screen sizes and below. I achieved this, however when the button is clicked, the nav links push the button and brand name down, and appear above them, within the navbar. I want them to appear below the navbar.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-light ">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a id="dominik" href="index.html"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
        </div>

<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-light p-4">
     </div>


           <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Chicken</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Beef</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Sushi</a>
            </li>
            </ul><!-- #nav-list -->


  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light d-sm-none">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not doing `navbar` as it is in [Official Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), in addition, you are putting two `nav` inside each other which is not mentioned in their documentation.

You can easily copy the `navbar` code from the documentation as is and then change the names of **URLs** as you like.

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4t752ft/8/).

Answer (score 0):

Update Code with this

```
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-light ">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a id="dominik" href="index.html"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
        </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light d-sm-none">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>

<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-light p-4">
     </div>


           <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Chicken</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Beef</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <br>Sushi</a>
            </li>
            </ul><!-- #nav-list -->


  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
```